# .NET WPF XAML Namespace Mapping for Enum types

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, xaml, enums

I'm binding a collection of my **W3CErrorOrWarning** type objects to controls in a WPF Window.

One of its properties is named "Type".  It is of type **W3CErrorOrWarningType** which is a simple Enum:

```
Enum W3CErrorOrWarningType
    ValidationError
    ValidationWarning
End Enum
```

I'm trying to use it in this way...

```
<Window ...
        xmlns:enums="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.XhtmlTextBox.W3CValidator.W3CResponse.W3CErrorOrWarning"
        ... />
    ...
    <DataTemplate>
        <Image Name="TypeIcon" ... />
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}">
                <DataTrigger.Value>
                    <enums:W3CErrorOrWarningType>
                        ValidationError
                    </enums:W3CErrorOrWarningType>
                </DataTrigger.Value>
                <Setter TargetName="TypeIcon"
                        Property="Source" 
                        Value="images/Error.png"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}">
                <DataTrigger.Value>
                    <enums:W3CErrorOrWarningType>
                        ValidationWarning
                    </enums:W3CErrorOrWarningType>
                </DataTrigger.Value>
                <Setter TargetName="TypeIcon"
                        Property="Source" 
                        Value="images/Warning.png"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I get this error:

> Undefined CLR namespace. The
>   'clr-namespace' URI refers to a
>   namespace
>   'WpfApplication1.XhtmlTextBox.W3CValidator.W3CResponse.W3CErrorOrWarning'
>   that is not included in the assembly.

My **WpfApplication1** project contains a user control **XhtmlTextBox**.  That user control contains a class called **W3CValidator** which contains a class called **W3CResponse** which contains a class called **W3CErrorOrWarning** which contains an enumeration called **W3CErrorOrWarningType**.

How do I enter the namespace for this type in my Window's XAML?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I think got it wrong, first time but ...

Are you including the enum name in the namespace ?

I should be:

```
xmlns:enums="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.XhtmlTextBox.W3CValidator.W3CResponse
```

considering all above are namespaces and not types, if W3CResponse is a type then you can't use the nested enum directly in XAML, XAML has no support for nested classes.

[Requirements for a Custom Class as a XAML Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753379.aspx)

> Your custom class must not be a nested
>   class